# Event in custom autocomplete combobox

Tags: javascript, html, autocomplete

I have a custom combo box, i search to intercept clic event when select élément of custom combo box.  What i should add?

```
$( function() {
        $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
          _create: function() {
            this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
              .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
              .insertAfter( this.element );


        this.element.hide();
        this._createAutocomplete();
        this._createShowAllButton();
      },

      _createAutocomplete: function() {
        var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
          value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

   ....
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: try this: `$('.custom-combobox').on('click', function(){// add logic here });`

Comment: It works for classic combobox but not for autocomplete custom combo box.